# automatic delete session variable within given time

Tags: node.js, express

I am setting a variable in session, but i want to automatic delete that variable from session. I there any method to achieve this ? or i thinking in wrong way.

basically i am setting OTP in session and i am deleting that OTP after verification. but i want to delete that OTP from session if user not providing within 500 seconds.

M setting OTP in session like: `req.session.otp = otp`

Deleting Like: `delete req.session.otp`

please some one guide me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting session after 500 sec can be achieved with following

```
setTimeout(function(){

  delete req.session.otp

}, 500000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use set timeout

```
setTimeout(function(){. //here clear a session. it will work}, 500000);
```